# Android ParseQuery.findInBackGround(callback) , the passed callback is never invoked

Tags: android, parse-platform

ParseQuery works okay in most cases, for querying tables in Parse.

But, ParseQuery.findInBackground(callback) only works for the first time, when called from within a fragment. When consecutive ParseQuery.findInBackground(callback) methods are called, the "callback" is never called by parse.

This only happens when used from an activity with multiple fragments and fragment tab-listener.
In normal activities and activities with one fragments ParseQueries work fine.

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

I've been having a similar problem.  The issue for me was that I was calling findInBackground multiple times too close together, so I guess it was having problems running two queries at the same time.  I fixed it by starting a new thread and calling find instead of findInBackground.  I don't know if that will help because I can't see your code.

Comment: Likewise! I actually had an update set to run onCreate and also onResume.. they were doing the same thing and neither EVER came back... weird. No logs, no errors, nothing.